# Error LogCat E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android-studio

tengo un problema con este error, que al parecer es lo que causa que mi aplicación, no muestre los mensajes obtenidos, ya que al entrar al activity que posee el RecyclerView en LogCat me marca este error: Adjunto image [Imagen error](https://prnt.sc/tu2vmv)

Antes de hacer este post me puse a buscar posibles soluciones y no di con ninguna, según lo que veo el error este es algo "común" cuando se usa recycler view, les adjunto los metodos donde hago uso de el RecyclerView

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Init Views
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ImageView profileIv;
    TextView nameTv, userStatusTv, nPrueba;
    EditText messageEt;
    ImageButton sendBtn;

    //Firebasse auth
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    //for checking if use has seen message or not
    ValueEventListener seenListener;
    DatabaseReference userRefForSeen;
    List<ModelChat> chatList;
    AdapterChat adapterChat;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

       Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarEv);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chat_recyclerView);
        nameTv = findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
        profileIv = findViewById(R.id.profileIv);
        messageEt = findViewById(R.id.messageEt);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);

        //layout (LinearLayout for RecycleView
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        //recyclerview properties
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChat);


                }

            }
```

y el otro fragmento del código donde también esta partes del RecyclerView es este:

```
 private void readMessages() {
        chatList = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                chatList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelChat chat = ds.getValue(ModelChat.class);
                    if(chat.getReceiver().equals(myUid) && chat.getSender().equals(hisUid) ||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(hisUid) && chat.getSender().equals(myUid)){
                        chatList.add(chat);
                    }
                    adapterChat = new AdapterChat(ChatActivity.this, chatList, hisImage);
                    adapterChat.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //set adapter to recyclerview
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChat);
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());





                }
            }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas Gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas definiendo un Adapter pero este no esta inicializado con datos

```
 ...
 ...
 AdapterChat adapterChat;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        ...
        ...
        ...
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChat);
    }

 ...
 ...
```

Puedes llamar `readMessages()` y posteriormente inicializar el Adapter llamando     `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChat);`

Comment: Bro ya acabe de intentar y no me funciono me sigue mandando el mismo error, o quizás lo hice mal, me podrías detallar un poco más tu respuesta?
Muchas gracias!